# I only get AT as feedback?

Tags: arduino, at-command, gprs

I am trying to connect with the SIM5215 chip trough the Cooking-hacks 3g Gprs board.
http://www.cooking-hacks.com/3g-gprs-shield-for-arduino-3g-gps

The connection with the chip is working fine. For example when in the serial monitor I use the command "AT+CPIN" I get a perfect response.

I can also play music from the flash drive and that works fine.

But as soon as I try to run one of the example scripts like the ftp script.
http://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/arduino-3g-gprs-gsm-gps

The only feedback I get in the serial monitor is.
AT
AT
AT
AT
AT
AT
And so on...

What does this mean? Does anybody know whats happening at this point?

My Serial Monitor is on both NL & CR and 115200 baud.
If I put At commands in the serial monitor to test the connection I get these responses.
    AT+CREG?+CREG: 0,1
    AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,"IP","internet" OK
    AT+CSOCKAUTH=1,1,"" "" OK
    AT + NETOPEN = "TCP", 60000 ERROR

I suspect there is a connection with this not working and me only receiving AT commands.
I also suspect I am doing something really stupid or that I am doing something wrong.

Help or just getting me on the right track is really appreciated.

Comment: I just found out there was a problem with the gprs antenna so it could not make a connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the hardware. The gprs antenna had problems connecting. By fixing this the problem was fixed.